# Excel - An unexpected error has occurred - Jump to a cell in a different sheet

Tags: excel

I have two Excel sheets, *S1* and *List*. S1 is included in List. The primary key is an ID number situated in column A in both sheets. I want to be able to jump from the small list to the big list to the same ID cell.

The formula I tried is the following, but I'm getting the "An unexpected error has occurred":

```
 =HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A2;List!A:A;1;FALSE);"VIEW")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *MATCH()* rather than *VLOOKUP()*:

```
=HYPERLINK("#List!A" & MATCH(A3;List!A:A,0);"view")
```